# java.io.StreamCorruptedException - Android

Tags: java, android, deserialization, objectinputstream

I am developing an application in which the file is downloaded from the server is encrypted. In the application I am trying to open an encrypted file stored in the internal storage to decrypt it:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new CipherInputStream(context.openFileInput("filename"), cipher));
String result = (String) ois.readObject();
```

But getting an exception:

> java.io.StreamCorruptedException

What does this error means in this case, and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamCorruptedException.html):

`Thrown when control information that was read from an object stream violates internal consistency checks.`

[From this helpful google search:](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/io/StreamCorruptedException.shtml)

`Essentially, what happens is that, somehow or other, the writing and the reading get "out of kilter". Here are a couple of ways it can happen:`

1. `Forgetting to close the ObjectOutputStream that wrote the data (or
   closing the wrong stream)`
2. `Forgetting to check the return value of InputStream.read().`